# Confirmation: can I debug an application while keeping a TCP socket open?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, tcpsocket

This question is just a confirmation question:

I'm working on a multi-threaded C# application, based on TCP sockets.
The connection looks unstable: it happens regularly that the connection falls after a while. I'm currently doing quite some tests, using breakpoints and single-stepping, using Visual Studio. I would like to be sure that the unstable connection is not simply caused by the fact that I'm debugging my application, hence this confirmation question:

Can hitting a breakpoint and doing some single-stepping cause a TCP socket connection to fail?

Comment: If no data is sent or received, then no, since TCP is designed for that. But many TCP applications implement some form of keepalive mechanism, and then the connection will break if no response is received due to the application being suspended. Likewise, if you suspend the application right after sending data, the connection can break since no packets can be acknowledged.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: ... and exactly that Keep-Alive mechanism is causing the communication to be dropped from the other side. Those Keep-Alive messages are sent back and forth by another thread in my application, therefore I believe it would be useful to have breakpoints who only break the current thread but let the other threads run, is that possible in Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: According to the docs, yes, through a [conditional breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/get-started-debugging-multithreaded-apps?view=vs-2017#bkmk_follow_a_thread). But I'm pretty sure what it's actually describing is still the usual scenario of the debugger suspending all threads when a breakpoint is hit (just with multiple threads running when you resume); I don't think there's a mode where it selectively resumes threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [Tracepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-tracepoints?view=vs-2019) to print dynamically information based on expressions/conditions. These won't block the currently executing thread so should work for something like this.